# How often do I have to login with Gmail API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I have a python script (and it works) that runs all day to search among my emails using Gmail API like this

```
def login():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    store = file.Storage(os.path.join(script_path, 'token.json'))
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(os.path.join(script_path, 'credentials.json'), SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    return service

def search(service):
    .
    .
    .
    return data
```

But I don't want to call login() more than I have to, so, my question would be...

How often do I have to login() to renovate the 'service' variable?

Inside 'token.json' there are 2 keys: "token_expiry" and "expires_in". And I think one of them has the answer but I'm not sure, Would be every hour or until token expiry?

```
"token_expiry": "2019-03-04T20:00:48Z",
"token_response": {
    "expires_in": 3600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"token_expiry": "2019-03-04T20:00:48Z",
"token_response": {
    "expires_in": 3600
```

The code return to you is an access token.  Access tokens expire after one hour `3600 Seconds = 60 Minutes`  You should only need to refresh it once every 55 minutes (there is something called clock skew which is why i dont say every 60 mintes)

Another thing you could do is just keep running your code as normal if you get an unauthorized error then catch that and run your login and try again.

You may also want to consider checking the python client library and see if it can handle refresh tokens this would allow your code to refresh the access as needed without you needing to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, actually there is no need to worry about, make one login at the start is enough, every call after that will renovate the service automatically if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The url below from Google has the answer you need. Basically it'll check if you have a token and if it's still valid or not. If already expired and the access_token has refresh_token, then it'll refresh the token, and if not valid then it'll request a new token.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python